# Dirty dishes at the top even after cleaning parts

Tags: dishwasher

I have a Maytag Quiet Series 300 dishwasher. I am not sure how old it is but I've been in this house for 5 years now. The dishwasher was never a superstar but recently it started washing dishes really badly. Specifically, the cups at the top come out with some sort of grime on them on the inside. They are perfectly clean on the outside. The bottom rack is also generally quite clean.

Here's a relatively extreme example of what I'm witnessing.
[image]

my first attempt was to clean the dish washer parts as seen on numerous YouTube videos. That didn't help much. We also tried running vinegar in an empty washer. I've also replaced the upper wash arm and one of the wash manifolds hoping they were clogged. None of that made much of a difference. I've also ran the wash empty with 4 cups flipped on the upper rack to confirm water is flowing up. They came out full of water as expected. I am getting desperate but before continuing to replace parts in the wash I was hoping someone could give me an educated guess on what could be the cause of this.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked for delivery of the rinse aid?

Comment: Blocked filter, leading to feeble spray?